# JDBC connection error for HIVE while using SQL WorkbenchJ

Tags: jdbc, hive

I am trying to establish a JDBC connection to access HIVE via SQL workbenchJ. I have placed all the JARs needed for connection along with the connection URL. Am getting the error

> [Amazon]HivejdbcDriver error initialized or created
>   transport for authentication:null

while testing the connection. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: "*I have placed all the JARs needed for connection along with the connection URL*" - did you _configure_ the JDBC driver in SQL Workbench as described in the [getting starting](http://www.sql-workbench.net/getting-started.html) section or in [Configuring JDBC drivers](http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/jdbc-setup.html)

Comment: I have placed the JAR files in a directory (D:\\Hive\Jar) and i have selected all the jar files placed in the directory while adding a new connection profile going to  manage drivers option.